# How to install this python modbus gateway?

Tags: modbus

I'm having trouble understanding how to install this python program https://github.com/3cky/mbusd
The instruction are there but I don't really know what to do with them.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/3cky/mbusd.git mbusd.git
$ cd mbusd.git
$ mkdir -p build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I guess it's obvious to those who know their stuff, and I'm not one of them apparently.
Can someone help me install and use this?

I'm trying to install this on a windows 10 PC btw.

thanks

I really didn't know where to begin with this one. I downloaded the files but didn't see any obvious "Install" file or anything

Comment: If you're on Windows, it might be easier for you to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux, then you'll need to install a compiler and then you'll be able to buld and run `mbusd`.

Comment: This app [does not appear to support Windows](https://github.com/3cky/mbusd/issues/1). As per the comments in that issue Cygwin *may* work or try WSL (as suggested above). An alternative would be to use Docker (as the repo includes a `Dockerfile`; you may find this easier than 'raw' WSL).